Exception log in opentelemetry are not exported to elasticsearch
I have a java application with logback opentelemetry appender that write data to a opentelemetry collector.
This is the collector configuration
  collector:
image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
container_name: collector
hostname: collector
command: [ "--config=/etc/collector-config.yaml" ]
volumes:
  - ./otel-backend-configuration/collector-config-local.yaml:/etc/collector-config.yaml
ports:
  - "5555:5555"
  - "6666:6666"

Where the yaml is the following
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:5555

processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 1s
    send_batch_size: 1024
  memory_limiter:
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_mib: 2000

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed
  otlp/elastic:
    # Elastic APM server https endpoint without the "https://" prefix
    endpoint: "http://fleet-server:8200"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers:
      # Elastic APM Server secret token
      Authorization: "Bearer supersecrettoken"

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [debug, otlp/elastic]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [debug, otlp/elastic]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [debug, otlp/elastic]

And this is the lockback configuration
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern> %-5level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} trace_id=%X{trace_id} span_id=%X{span_id} trace_flags=%X{trace_flags} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Just wrap your logging appender, for example ConsoleAppender, with OpenTelemetryAppender -->
    <appender name="OTEL" class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.mdc.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </appender>

    <!-- Use the wrapped "OTEL" appender instead of the original "CONSOLE" one -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="OTEL"/>
    </root>

</configuration>

I'm using elasticsearch with fleet as backend.
In my java app I have this method
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/appError")
public Response error() {
    log.error("Error in application log");
    RuntimeException errorInApplication = new RuntimeException("Error in application");
    log.error("Error prova", errorInApplication);
    throw errorInApplication;
}

When I search in kibana i'm only able to see the "Error in application log" but not the exception and the stacktrace.
If I look at my collector log I can see the exception as reported below
LogRecord #1

ObservedTimestamp: 2024-07-31 12:50:33.521778909 +0000 UTC
Timestamp: 2024-07-31 12:50:33.494 +0000 UTC
SeverityText: ERROR
SeverityNumber: Error(17)
Body: Str(Error)
Attributes:
     -> exception.message: Str(Error in application)
     -> exception.stacktrace: Str(java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in application
        at com.test.opentelemetry_test.HelloAppController.error(HelloAppController.java:81)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)

How can I solve this? I think it could be a misconfiguration but I cannot understand where.
